# Opening PDF's including a separate annotations file

Tags: windows, pdf, annotation, knowledge-organization

PDF's can be annotated with comments and highlights. I believe the data of such annotations are typically stored in the meta data of the PDF file itself. However, there is also a separate format for saving the annotations next to the PDF (https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html).

The OS application Skim implements something similar and allows you to save annotations as a *.skim* file (https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/manual/SkimHelp_43.html).

Mendeley also seems to implement separate annotations, as opening the PDF files with a different viewer will not show the annotations (https://www.mendeley.com/guides/desktop/04-read-highlight-annotate). However, it is unclear to me where these annotations live.

Foxit Reader allows the user to import and export annotations as a separate *.fdf* file, but it requires multiple additional steps and clicks by the user (https://www.foxitsoftware.com/blog/using-comments-data-import-and-export/).

Having a separate annotation file can be helpful for multiple reasons, including working with a *Git repository* where the PDF's are uploaded once (or even *gitignored*), while the smaller annotations file is tracked by *Git*.

Is there software for Windows which allows you to annotate PDF documents and which can *by default* save these in a separate file and *by default* load the annotations when opening the PDF?

Comment: Mendeley stores annotations separately on their servers and possibly usefully splits annotations for a given file on the view that you are using so that you can have private annotations & shared.

Comment: Also an automatic comment extraction tool would do the job, since the world uses Acrobat to annotate pdfs

Comment: @Julian_W Yeah, potentially. Though key to my request is the *automatic* part, both in extracting the annotations for saving and sharing, as well as *automatic* in loading the annotations when opening the pdf file.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux I use **[Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/)** for this, which saves annotations etc. into an external file in XML format – and can be configured to automatically open that file along with the main PDF. Xournal is also available for Windows from the linked page.

[image: Xournal]
<sup>*Xournal* screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

The XML format used by Xournal has another advantage: You can always edit that directly to fix some markers, be it text corrections or aligning the positions.

I'm using *Xournal* for over a year on Linux, and I'm quite satisfied. Only doing "light stuff" with it, though – and of course it takes a little "getting used to".

From their [manual](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/manual.html#pdfannotate): "*A journal is composed of one or more pages. Each page consists of a background and one or more layers stacked on top of the background. All drawing operations take place within a single layer. Xournal can be used to annotate PDF files, by loading the pages of a PDF file as backgrounds for a journal. By default, the PDF file used to generate the backgrounds will not be saved with the journal; instead, the journal file will contain a reference to the absolute location of this file.*"

Comment: Awesome! This will do. Not exactly the PDF annotations I was hoping for (so if anyone else has suggestions, please answer), but certainly a useful tool.